# Is this normal and should I be concerned about square on my ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, patching-drywall

Is this normal and should I be concerned about square on my ceiling? Should I worry about any leaks? I felt the spot and it’s cold to the touch but not soft, no wet. Although I am wondering why it feels cooler compared to the rest of the ceiling when felt by hand.

Here’s a picture

[image: My Ceiling]

Comment: What's above that section of the ceiling?  Looks to me like it may have been patched for some reason in the past.

Comment: I’m on the top floor so above it is just the roof outside.

Comment: Do not think you need to worry.  With it feeling cooler, it is one of two things, one a patch job done from when roof did leak and they did not replace the insulation well, or two it was an access hatch and patched over it(seems like right size).  Your landlord can confirm.  They could have done better job on patch.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody else worried about the leaks and this is the results of someone  fixing them in all probability. With limited access to the attic, you would have to cut an access area out to get to the problem and fix it. It looks like they used thicker drywall to repair the ceiling than what was there before. It's a shame they didn't do it right because the texture was done after the repair and it could have been unnoticeable. The cold feeling is probably due to the insulation not being replaced before adding the drywall.

Comment: They just replaced the roof to all the apartments right before I moved in. I lived right next door. Do you think it’ll leak?

Comment: In my humble opinion, I think you'll be fine, especially since they just replaced the roof.